# Unity incompatibility in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have this problem where I can't actually do anything {Autofill, MonoBehaviour not showing, everything is incompatible}.
You can see more in the screenshot.

[image: Incompatibility with unity]

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Unity on Visual studios ?

Find 'visual studio installer' on start Search, Click on 'Modify' and make sure under gaming you have Unity installed

[image]
[image]

Next in the Unity Editor, select the Edit > Preferences menu >  External Tools
find External Script Editor and set as follow

[image]

Make sure to Restart when you are done :)

For more info

https://forum.unity.com/threads/visual-studio-2019-setup.702953/

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows